# SQL SERVER: Get Column names from a Table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to get column names from tables using this:

```
SELECT NAME FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TABLE')
```

But I want to know how can I do the equivalent with a variable:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(id int, column1, column 2)

SELECT NAME FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table) --this don't work
```

Comment: See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/298681/220697

Comment: You can use `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` if you declare the table variable in the same batch: `SELECT name FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'DECLARE @Table TABLE(id int);SELECT * FROM @Table;', NULL, 0);`